# average function not operating returning NULL - DATETIME

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, join

I am using sqlserver 2005.

**I have table tradefile with following important columns :**

```
Scrip_Code : nvarchar(25)
Sauda_Date : datetime   [value example: 3/1/2013 9:15:04 AM]
TradeType  : nvarchar(5)
Market_Rate: float
```

I wanted to take average of Market Rate for particular sauda_date,scrip_code and tradetype.

**For that i fired following query:**

```
select avg(Market_Rate) 
from tradefile 
where 
Scrip_Code='ACC' and 
Sauda_Date =convert(datetime,'03/21/2013')
```

This query returning me null value.

What is mistake in above query?

**Note:** sauda_date is datetime and has both time and date as shown in above exmple [3/1/2013 9:15:04 AM]

Please guid me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'03/21/2013')
```

If you run the above, it will print:

```
2013-03-21 00:00:00.000
```

So you try to match this to something with a time:

```
2013-03-21 09:15:04.123
```

It will obviously not match.

**You need to convert both to DATE.**

```
Sauda_Date >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '03/21/2013') AND 
Sauda_Date < DATEADD(dd, 1, CONVERT(DATETIME, '03/21/2013'))
```

Derived from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1848450/1711796).

[Test](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dbddd/5).

**EDIT:** Removed `CONVERT(DATE, Sauda_Date)` approach because `DATE` is not defined in SQL Server 2005 and because it [might be a bad idea](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea).

Comment: nope not working, in either of the way, should i add something like CONVERT(DATE, '03/21/2013',101) to answer???

Comment: @Freelancer I believe adding `101` shouldn't matter since you call the same function on both, and the output is `DATE`, which shouldn't store formatting information. [Here's a test that works](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/55eed/1). It could help to identify a single row which *should* match and try to figure out why it doesn't.

Comment: Yeah , on demo its working, in place of DATE i am using datetime since i m with sqlserver 2005.

Comment: I tried to edit your query and it worked with: CONVERT(varchar(11), Sauda_Date) = CONVERT(datetime, '03/21/2013')

Comment: just edit your answer with CONVERT(varchar(11), Sauda_Date) = CONVERT(datetime, '03/21/2013') I will mark it as answer.

Comment: @Freelancer Edited with another solution which should work in SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is that your `where` clause filtered out all rows, or that `Market_Rate` was always `NULL`. Execute the following debug query to confirm:

```
select * --debug
from tradefile 
where 
Scrip_Code='ACC' and 
Sauda_Date =convert(datetime,'03/21/2013')
```

Comment: no this query returns 0 rows, and when i remove Sauda_Date from where then only it returns result.

Comment: Why do you say "no"? What do you mean by that? It looks like you found the problem?!

Comment: no means, i wanted to say, query was not operating, sorry, english is not my primary language thats why some mistakes in sentence structure can be there. dont take it wrong.

Comment: Np. So the query returned no rows - then AVG can also not return anything but NULL. Don't you agree? AVG of zero rows is NULL.

Comment: yeah, but i can clearly see in my DB that it should return the average of 4 different Marketrates.