# Display a date that is the same as today in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named Test and I want to display the info only from the current date.

I tried to do something like this but doesn't work if I use =

```
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE graduated = GETDATE()
```

And here is the table

```
------------------------------------------------
|  id         |  name           | graduated           |
------------------------------------------------
| 1      | John          | 2016-06-20         |
------------------------------------------------
| 2      | Amy          | 2016-06-20         |
------------------------------------------------
| 3      | Lily          | 2016-06-21         |
------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: what's the datatype for the `graduated` field? date? datetime?

Comment: Also see [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1843395/335858).

Comment: The data type from the graduated field it's date

Comment: try `WHERE DATEDFIFF(day, graduated, GETDATE()) = 0`.  `GETDATE` also includes the time component which is throwing off your equality check.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Test WHERE graduated =  CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)` It is because GETDATE has hours min and seconds, and your dates do not.  The casting as only date removes the hours min and seconds.

Comment: `WHERE CAST(graduated AS DATE) =  CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)`

Comment: Both getdate() and the valued in your graduated column include time components. For example, getdate() might return `2016-06-21 08:58:18.139`. This value is not equal to `2016-06-21 00:00:00.000` in the  graduated column in the same way that `3.14159` does not equal `3.00000`.