# Convert date time field to date and check the value

Tags: sql, datetime, type-conversion

Is it possible to convert field entry that has date and time, to only date and check that this value equals TODAY in SQL query?

There is field `EntryDate` with values like `Tuesday, October 04, 2016 12:00 AM` - can I somehow convert this to just date, and compare it to equal TODAY?

Thanks

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Is `EntryDate` of a proper `timestamp` type? If so, casting to `date` is the first part: https://modern-sql.com/feature/extract#related-cast   The other part is comparing it to `current_date`. If `EntryDate` is a string type, you have a bad time ahead :(

Comment: This is a trivial variation on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1843395/224704   It should help even if you aren't using SQL Server. If you are using SQL Server, your question can be considered a duplicate.

Comment: have you tried Convert function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it Timestamp? If so then just cast it for Date.

```
SELECT CAST(tstamp AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be in luck if you are using SQL Server:

```
    select PARSE('Tuesday, October 04, 2016 12:00 AM' as datetime)
```

And for the sake of completeness, you can compare to the date part of today's date.

```
    SELECT
    CASE WHEN PARSE('Tuesday, October 04, 2016 12:00 AM' as datetime) = CONVERT(date, getdate()) THEN 'YES'
    ELSE 'NO' END
```