# Filtering GridView entries by date

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, visual-studio, parameters

In Visual Studio ASP.NET

#### Code:

```xml
<asp:sqldatasource id="sqldatasource3" 
                   runat="server" 
                   connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VPSConnectionString %>" 
                   selectcommand="SELECT [Price], [Date], [Route_Start], [Route_Destination] FROM [Billing] WHERE ([Username] = @Username)">
  <SelectParameters>
    <asp:SessionParameter Name="Username" 
                          SessionField="username_universal" 
                          Type="String" />
  </SelectParameters>
</asp:sqldatasource>
```

#### Database:

[image]

Im trying to filter the entries on the webpage based on the date to the current date. I have successfully filtered by the username but I can't seem to figure out how to use the current date within this .aspx file.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post the code instead of posting screenshots of the code.

Comment: I have edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just the current date, you could use the SQL `GETDATE()` function. In order to match date only, you'll need to either do a `CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)` or `FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT))` in your query to properly match.

Example:

```
SELECT [Price]
,   [Date]
,   [Route_Start]
,   [Route_Destination] 
    FROM [Billing] 
    WHERE [Username] = @Username 
      AND CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) = CAST([Date] AS DATE)
```

See also: [Compare DATETIME and DATE ignoring time portion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843395/compare-datetime-and-date-ignoring-time-portion)

Comment: For anyone who finds this, also to compare dates for greater than or less than. [&lt;=, %lt, %gt; %gt;=] equals [<=, <, >, >=]